# Display popup with text and graphics on mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to have a popup window such that when the user hovers mouse over the image, it displays that popup window on the right of the image. The window would contain text as well as graphics. The window should close the moment my mouse is out of the image. I tried various scripts that are on the internet, but they show the text as innerhtml of the same page. So that breaks my original page. Is there a way to have a box with text and graphics come up when I roll over the image and go away when I close it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out jQuery qtip -- http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/

Demos: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/

---

Edit: Sample Code (straight from QTip's demo site). This will give the effect seen on http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/content/basic

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="your/path/to/qtip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Create the tooltips only on document load
$(document).ready(function() 
{
   // Match all link elements with href attributes within the content div
   $('#content a[href]').qtip(
   {
      content: 'Some basic content for the tooltip' // Give it some content, in this case a simple string
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I do not want to install anything. Is it possible to achieve this just using a script?

Comment: qtip is just a script, similarly to how jquery is just a script. If you don't use a plugin like these, then yes, it is possible, but it won't be as pretty. I'll write a small one up, one sec.

Comment: actually, it's more of a pain that i remembered. You have to get the offset of the image, apply a bunch of css, remove it all, etc. Honestly, these plugins are much easier.

Comment: Can you please show me a sample script of how to achieve this. I am new to jquery and script at above website seems very confusing to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to catch only mouseover and mouseleave events, maybe you should simply try to use only CSS and :hover selector on image or div, if target browsers let it.